# Enlarge row-height dynamically with pictures size

Tags: image, latex, tabular

I am building a table in LaTeX that contains a column of pictures. I would like the size of the rows related to those pictures to increase their height such that the picture stays inside its cell. I tried the `\\[2cm]` solution, but then the text in the cells of the same rows is not centered anymore. An example to be clearer:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c c c|c c c}

    \multirow{ 2}{*}{} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{\textbf{mesh}} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{\textbf{dofs}} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{\textbf{levels}} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{iterations}} & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{\textbf{Conv Rate}}  \\ \cline{5-10}
    & & & & \footnotesize{SGMG} & \footnotesize{NMG} & \footnotesize{AMG} & \footnotesize{SGMG}  & \footnotesize{NMG} & \footnotesize{AMG}\\\hline
    
    \multirow{ 2}{*}{\textbf{1D}} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{\includegraphics[scale = .2]{path1}& \multirow{ 2}{*}{100k} & 2 & -&- & - & - & - & -  \\
    & & & 5 & -& -& - & - & - & -  \\ \hline
    
 \multirow{8}{*}{\textbf{2D}} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{\includegraphics[scale = .1]{path2}& \multirow{2}{*}{100k} & 2 & -&- & - & - & - & -  \\
    & & & 5 & -& -& - & - & - & -  \\[2cm] \cline{2-10}
    
    & \multirow{ 2}{*}{mesh22} &  \multirow{2}{*}{100k} & 2 & -&- & - & - & - & -  \\
    &  & & 5 & -& -& - & - & - & -  \\ \cline{2-10}
    
     &\multirow{ 2}{*}{mesh23}  &  \multirow{2}{*}{100k}& 2 & -&- & - & - & - & -  \\
    & & & 5 & -& -& - & - & - & -  \\ \cline{2-10}
    
    & \multirow{ 2}{*}{mesh24}&   \multirow{2}{*}{100k}& 2 & -&- & - & - & - & -  \\
    & & & 5 & -& -& - & - & - & -  \\ \hline
    
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: thanks, now should be ok

Answer (score 0):

Different approach: instead of merging the cell with your image, you could make the other cells have multiple lines

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c|m{2cm}|Y|Y|YYY|YYY}
\hline
  \multirow{9}{*}{2D} & \includegraphics[scale=.2,valign=t]{example-image-duck} & 100k & 2 \linebreak 5 & -\linebreak -&-\linebreak - & -\linebreak - & -\linebreak - & -\linebreak - & -\linebreak - \\
  \cline{2-10}
    & \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=3cm,valign=t]{example-image-duck} & 100k & 2 \linebreak 5 & -\linebreak -&-\linebreak - & -\linebreak - & -\linebreak - & -\linebreak - & -\linebreak - \\
  \hline   
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

... or if you prefer vertically centred cells:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{multirow}

\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c|m{2cm}|Y|Y|YYY|YYY}
\hline
  \multirow{9}{*}{2D} & \includegraphics[scale=.2,valign=b]{example-image-duck} & 100k & 2 \linebreak 5 & -\linebreak -&-\linebreak - & -\linebreak - & -\linebreak - & -\linebreak - & -\linebreak - \\
  \cline{2-10}
    & \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=3cm,valign=b]{example-image-duck} & 100k & 2 \linebreak 5 & -\linebreak -&-\linebreak - & -\linebreak - & -\linebreak - & -\linebreak - & -\linebreak - \\
  \hline   
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, but the problem of values non vertically centered stays! In your 2nd row, it would be nice to see the '100k' vertically centered in the long column

Comment: @Cla I added a second solution

Comment: Ok I'm trying to put this solution in my example, but for now no news

Comment: Not sure why, but did not seem to work ok with my own pictures. the left '2D' is not centered even if I just copy and paste your code

Comment: @KJ Sure, the question was to vertically centre, why should they be centred horizontally?

Comment: @KJ The comment explicitly speaks of the `100k` and `2D` columns, and even though they are centred, it makes no sense to ask to centre them horizontally because they anyway fill the whole width.

Comment: @KJ Where on Earth do you get that from? The question is about "Enlarge row-height dynamically with pictures size", the vertical alignment was just a bonus